# Running WCF WebAPI Prev 6 inside MVC3 on AppHarbor, 404 Errors

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, appharbor

I was trying to throw a quick WCF WebAPI project together up on AppHarbor tonight and ran into some issues. The WCF API is couched inside an empty MVC3 project just like is demo'd on the WCF CodePlex site. https://github.com/jptoto/Postmark-Response-Code-Generator The API itself is quite basic, when you type an http response error code on the end of the url the response will be the proper error code. So, for example, using http://responsecodes.appharbor.com/api/response/405 in Fiddler or some other http client will return the proper error response for a 405 error. (This API is just a convenient way to test with proper error responses).

Anyway, no matter what I try I get 404 errors from AH. I can't tell if the routing isn't working on what. When I download the built code from AH and run it locally inside IIS it runs fine, no problem.

If AH just doesn't support some kind of routing that is in WebAPI Preview 6 that's fine. I just want to cover all my bases. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong URL and that your app is running here: http://responsecodes.apphb.com/api/response/406

(`apphb` instead of `appharbor`)